# QGIS: Style-"Rule-Based"

Tags: qgis, style, classification, add-in, rule-based

Style: Rule-Based
 Please be informed that the Add Categories to Rule under the "Refine Current Rules" does not filter in accordance to the selected layer that you have chosen. Instead, all subcategories are being displayed. It does not automatically trim down to specific content as filtered/classified and that makes it harder to select only what is really necessary. I hope that they will make an update to this so that using QGIS will make it more fun to use.

Comment: Hi, welcome to gis.se. I cannot see any question here. Please modify this post to become a question. In any case, it's a good idea to take the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I understand your point. Adding subcategory to rule-based style is not working in QGIS 2.16.2, but actually it works using QGIS 2.14.6 long term release (LTR).

Here is the output using Rule-Based Style without refine by subcategory:

[image]

Here is the refine after adding subcategry:

[image]

Only the subcategory economy under the category "Country" are styled.

Since QGIS 2.16.2 is not considered LTR, I highly recommend to use QGIS 2.14.6 LTR to avoid such problems.

Comment: good job, ahmadhanb, that is exactly what I wanted to tell.  You got it right. By the way, I am using QGIS 2.10 Pisa.  Is there anyway that they can fix this one but not downloading QGIS 2.14.6 LTR?  Thank you

Comment: @wgs84 Please report this issue on the QGIS bug tracker. GIS.stackexchange is not the right platform.

Comment: FYI - This issue is fixed in the daily builds and the next release of 2.16 will include the fix. In the meantime the refine controls work OK if use the "map styling dock" rather then going through layer properties.

Comment: to @ahmadhanb I tried and used QGIS 2.17 LTR but it seems the problem was not fixed at all. Anymore recommendation? thanks

Comment: @wgs84 What is the problem of using 2.14.6 LTR? I did not try 2.17 so I cannot judge. But I know it worked in 2.14.6.

Comment: It looks to me that this issue is back in QGIS 2.18.